# Angular 2 way to get item from Observable<Xyz[]>

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Given the following Typescript in an Angular 2 service:

```
getLanguages () {
    return this.http.get(this._languagesUrl)
        .map(res => <Language[]> res.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

I'm having difficulty using this in circumstances where I need to lookup a specific item from the array. For example, I can't do the following because `filter` expects an `Observable<Language>` rather than an the `Observable<Language[]>` that is being returned.

```
getLanguages().filter(language => language.id == 3) // Error
```

I appreciate that my issue may be that I'm mixing synchronous and asynchronous behavior, so Ill provide my use case: User can enter a language id and I want to display the associated language name. I want to leverage `getLanguages()` with the `Observable` result because it is already being used elsewhere in the project. I also want implement some caching so the HTTP request doesn't get made each time I do a lookup.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example working of what you want to do:

https://plnkr.co/edit/lK47pVaW8b0CEez0mum4?p=preview

Press F12 in chrome to see the logs to give you a more clear idea of what's going on and why it doesn't work in your example.

Take a special atention to:

```
constructor(private _langService: LanguagesService) {
    _langService.getLanguages() //We get an Observable<Array> object returned.
        //So this is the observable's filter function:
        .filter( this._filter3rdLanguage )
        //The filter gets called only once and its comparing an observable object, not a language object.
        //that's why nothing gets filtered:
        .do( o => console.log(o) )
        //If you filter the actual list instead of the observable object, you'll get it called several times.
        //This is the Array's filter function.
        .subscribe( list => this.languages = list.filter( this._filter3rdLanguage ) );
}
```

This is another, maybe better, way to do it:

```
  _langService.getLanguages()
    .map( list => list.filter(this._filter3rdLanguage) )
    //see that this one IS filtered.
    .do( list => console.log(list) )
    .subscribe( list => this.languages = list );
```

Comment: Thanks!  Logging items to the console in this way helped me see that I'm only getting one object, which is an array of the objects i want to filter on.

Answer (score 7):

finding item in Observable<Type>

```
    let item: Language;
    langugages. // observable cached data
        .subscribe((items: Language[]) => item = items.find(p => p.id == 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mergeMap` instead of `map` to flatten out the array:

```
getLanguages () {
    return this.http.get(this._languagesUrl)
        .flatMap(res => Rx.Observable.fromArray(<Language[]> res.json().data))
        .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

Now the return value from `getLanguages` will be an `Observable<Language>`

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the `map` method with `subscribe`, you can access members of the `Language` array when the array is available:

```
return this.http.get(this._languagesUrl)
  .map(res => <Language[]> res.json().data)
  .subscribe((languages: Language[]) => alert(languages[3]); );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a guess, since I haven't used RxJS personally, though I am interested in it. Perusing the docs, I wonder if the following would work:

```
function getLanguageName(id: number): Observable<string> {
    return getLanguages()
              .map((langs: Language[]) => _.find(langs, { id: id }))
              .pluck('name');
}
```

I used Lodash's `_.find()` to find the matching record in the array, but if you don't have it, you can always do the search manually or use `.filter(langs, ...)[0]`.

If you want to do caching, and you know that the name of a language for a given id will never change, you could use Lodash's `_.memoize()` function to reuse the output for a given input.

I'm curious to see if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For a customer service app I'm supporting, I needed a way to hide or show buttons depending on whether or not a user account had a particular line of business, and I needed to act upon the async data being loaded on the page, and not necessarily use the data as-is.  So I'm calling a method from the template and using map with find then subscribe.

```
      <button *ngIf="(lobs$ | async) ? getButtonVisibility('internet') : false" class="eing-account-header-drawers-button" (click)="openDrawer(drawers[drawers.internet],$event)">


public getButtonVisibility(lobName: string) {
  let isVisible;
  this.lobs$.map(x =>
    x.findIndex(y =>
      y.lobName.toLowerCase() == lobName.toLowerCase() && y.hasLob))
        .subscribe(x => { isVisible = x != -1});
  return isVisible;      
}
```