# Filtering Firestore Observable against javascript object values

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Observable dataset that I get from a Firestore query using the angularfire2 snapshotChanges function.  I'm able to get the info and display it fine, so that is all working.  What I am having a hard time with is the following.  The observable contains teams that the user has already selected to include in their account.  When they go through the "Add Team" stepper, I want to highlight teams that they have already added and not allow them to re-add them.  I have a service that manages the data store for the user's team and I want to add a unique check to that service.

Given that background, here is the service function, uniqCheck, that I have been messing with for three days now and can't get to work. The .do method doesn't output anything, which leads me to believe that the .map method isn't doing what I think it should be doing, however no errors are thrown in the console.  I shouldn't have to go back to the database to validate this, as I already have the observable in the client. I've included my load function for reference.  The uniqCheck function is what I am trying to solve for.

What I am trying currently,  [I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351922/angular-2-way-to-get-item-from-observablexyz).

Any suggestions?

```
private _collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
public store_userteams: Observable<any[]> = null;

load(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // console.log('load user team records for user ' + this._session.currentuser.uid);
    this._collection = this._firedb.collection<any>('userteams', ref => ref.where('userid', '==', this._session.currentuser.uid ));
    this.store_userteams = this._collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
    resolve(true);
  });
}

// tta is a javascript collection passed in from the component function.  tta.id is valid and correct
uniqCheck(tta): Promise<any> {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
   let matchcount = 0;
   console.log(tta.id);
   this.store_userteams
   .map( teams => teams.filter(team => team.teaminfo.id===tta.id) )
   .do( teams => console.log('filtered teams: ' + teams) )
   .subscribe( teams => matchcount = teams.length );
   console.log('matchcount: ' + matchcount);
   resolve(matchcount);
 });
}
```

Comment: why uniqCheck function returns a Promise, it can be a simple return value function, use undersocrejs each and/or filter on the store_userteams, i think that should do the work for you.

Comment: That's what I actually started with, but since store_userteams is an Observable, underscore can't work with it.  Ideally, there would just a method to get the underlying data out of store_userteams, but there doesn't seem to be so.  Point of clarification is that store_userteams is an observable as a result of a Firestore query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the solution below won't make store_userteams as Observable and also `id` will be in every object so it's easy to perform javascript related filters(underscore or vanilla)

```
load() {
    this.loadData().subscribe(data => {
        this.store_userteams = _.pluck(data, 'data');
    });
}
loadData() {
    this._collection = this._firedb.collection<any>('userteams', ref => ref.where('userid', '==', this._session.currentuser.uid ));
    return this._collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            data.id = id;

            return { data };
        });
    });
}
```

And now in `uniqCheck` function you can use the `store_userteams` object

```
uniqCheck(tta) {
    // underscore or vanilla js filter on this.store_userteams
    console.log(tta);
    console.log('this.store_userteams : ', this.store_userteams);
}
```

Hope this helps!